# Unity Launcher and panel Missing after update of Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: unity, launcher

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 xenial and rebooted the system, but after the reboot no launcher and panel appear in screen. Mouse right click is working, even I can start any applications from terminal it's working fine, but no menu bar for applications are being displayed and many shortcuts are also not working(ex-ALT+TAB to switch between application). I googled it and got so many solutions but none of them worked for me. I installed CCSM tool, tried to delete `.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` directory, tried some Intel Graphics driver tricks but eventually I end up with no solution.

I created other accounts, for new accounts it's working fine.

Comment: This happened to me few hours ago. For me, even new accounts don't login, but pop out to the login screen. Only Guest profile works. No solution worked for me either. This is what I get on "setsid unity":
`compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
We're already using profile 'unity', no need to switch
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 3244
unity7 start/running, process 3290`